# How to load a JSON file in Python keeping some escaped Unicode characters

Tags: python, json, encoding, escaping

I'm trying to parse a json file that have some escaped unicode characters on it's values for some processing.

It comes that when I open the file to work on it, python converts the escaped characters to the actual ascii character, but I need to keep the characters escaped, due to a requirement of the tool that will later process this file.

I tried opening the file with different encodings and also tried both options (True and False) for the `ensure_ascii` option on the json.dump function.

But the problem really seems to be when I load the file, as the example bellow:

This is an simple json file to be used as input:

```
{
    "id": "my_current_id",
    "name": "dockeradmin \u003e aclpolicy",
    "content": "description: Read \u0026 Execute permissions."
}
```

This is a model that I'm using to simplify the test of different solutions

```
import json

with open('./test.json', encoding='utf-8') as tfstateFile:
    tfstateData = json.load(tfstateFile)
    tfstateData['id'] = 'my_new_id'
    print(tfstateData['id'])
    print(tfstateData['name'])
    print(tfstateData['content'])

    resultFilePath = '/result/test_result.json'
    with open(resultFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as resultStateFile:
        json.dump(tfstateData, resultStateFile, indent=4, sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False)
```

When I use the provided json as input, this is the output I'm receiving:

```
>>> my_new_id
>>> dockeradmin > aclpolicy
>>> description: Read & Execute permissions.
```

The output file is also decoding the escaped characters:

```
{
    "id": "my_new_id",
    "name": "dockeradmin > aclpolicy",
    "content": "description: Read & Execute permissions."
}
```

Is it possible to load the json file and keep the escaped characters on the strings values?

The resultant output should be:

```
{
    "id": "my_new_id",
    "name": "dockeradmin \u003e aclpolicy",
    "content": "description: Read \u0026 Execute permissions."
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this - these codepoints are within the ASCII range, so even decoding with [raw-]unicode-escape will not preserve the '\uxxxx' escapes.

Comment: yes, I am guessing that too. I`ll try to escape the escaped characters before processing it, so that python dont convert to the real character, then I will convert it back to the escaped character.

Comment: Do you already have a solution? Also: Can you explain why the JSON result must not contain literal `>` or `&`? If a tool (which one?) forbids that, it seems to me that it's a bug in that tool and should be fixed there and not by the user of the tool (you).